# Will React Native input's text available in a RAM memory dump be garbage collected at some point? How long would that take?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Long story short, I need to confirm that text written inside some inputs would eventually be cleared from the RAM memory so that it can't be accessed through a memory dump. From what I understand, since I'm using a high level programming language, I can't manually manipulate the memory and rely entirely on the garbage collector.

I am using frida server and fridump to create the RAM dump and I'm testing on Android right now.

Now I am wondering how long must I wait before the strings in the memory get garbage collected? I am creating the memory dump after the Stack that contains the input fields gets unmounted, so I imagine that they should be eligible for deletion at that point.

That being said, I've waited a long time inbetween dumps while the application is running, and it seems that the strings are not being removed from memory.

Comment: In a nutshell if your object have reference to another object for example to the TextInput Value property it wont be Garbage Collected, GC release from memory only objects that have 0 references.

Comment: @ko100v.d So in my scenario, is there anything I can do to resolve my issue? How can I know or make sure that these strings are removed from my memory?

Comment: You will have to provide your code, your question isn’t clear enough